# JavaScript AJAX XMLHttpRequest on "Post" request the call back function "onload" does work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here I have tried to use AJAX for sending data to server, In server side I have used PHP,I used post request, data gets sent to the server successfully and also sends message to the client side, but on the client side the "onload" call back function doesn't get called. Please Help.

Here the frontend code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function postUser() {
      if(validityCheck()) {
          let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhr.open("POST", "./api/user/create.php", true);
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
              xhr.send(extractFormValues());
            xhr.onload = function() {
                alert("Hi");
            }
      }
      else {
        alert("Please fill the form correctly");
      }

    }

    function validityCheck() {
        if(document.getElementById("name").checkValidity()) {
            if(document.getElementById("age").checkValidity()) {
                return true ;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false ;
        }
    }

    function extractFormValues() {
        let nam = document.getElementById("name").value;
        let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        let user = {"name":nam,"age":age}
        return (JSON.stringify(user))
    }
</script>
<div>
  <h2>Let AJAX</h2>
    <form method="post">
      <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br>
      <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="age" name="age"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="postUser()">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the server side code in php :

```
<?php
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization,X-Requested-With');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/User.php';
  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  // Instantiate blog post object
  $user = new User($db);

  // Get raw posted data
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// need to check the data is valid or not

  $user->name = $data->name;
  $user->age = $data->age;

  // Create Category
  if($user->create()) {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'User Created')
    );
  } else {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'User Not Created')
    );
  }
```

I have tested the server code using api tester it works fine also gives the response. The only problem is the user gets created but the onload function doesn't gets called.

Comment: From the look of your form, you're both submitting the form to the server *and* doing an XHR call. (You probably don't want both.) Change your `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="postUser()">` line to `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="postUser()">` and you'll most likely see your issue.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Use the more modern and flexible [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) over the older XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thank you,
Steve Gomez finally your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `onload()` before you call send().
It's called after send is called. When you assign it to onload, you're not calling it. You're just defining it so that it's there when XHR needs to call it.

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("POST", "./api/user/create.php", true);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
          xhr.onload = function() {
                  alert("Hi");
               };
          xhr.send(extractFormValues());
```

[MDN Docs Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#example_get)